# Can you re-equip equipment to the same creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Murderer's Axe](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=410025) has an equip cost: discard a card, and since madness runs off discarding, this can be rather useful.
Can an equipment card be re-equipped to the same creature that already has it equipped?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can choose the currently equipped creature to target with the equip ability since it doesn't require the target to be a different creature.

Note that if you have other cards that care about things becoming (un)equipped or (un)attached they will not trigger since the equipment never actually stops being equipped, and it doesn't gain a new timestamp.

> **702.6a** Equip is an activated ability of Equipment cards. “Equip [cost]” means “[Cost]: Attach this permanent to target creature you control. Activate this ability only any time you could cast a sorcery.”

Comment: Unless the Equipment is a Lightning Greaves.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that 701.3b specifically covers the case of attaching an object to something it's already attached to.

Answer (score 4):

Since there is no restriction (other than control) based on the wording of "equip", I'd say yes.

> **702.6a** Equip is an activated ability of Equipment cards. “Equip [cost]” means “[Cost]: Attach this permanent to target creature you control. Activate this ability only any time you could cast a sorcery.”

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. That card doesn't specifically mention anything about its equip ability having to be used on a different creature and not on one it's already attached to.

A good rule of thumb with Magic: Unless the card specifically states something, more oft than not you do exactly what is says on the card and nothing else.

So since it doesn't specifically tell you to only equip it to a different creature, then you're good to go.

Enjoy that madness ability!

Comment: I'm not sure this logic really works well in this case. The card doesn't really say *anything* about how the equip ability works; it just says "Equip." You have to look at the rules to figure out what it actually means. The sorcery-speed restriction for Equip is a nice example: if you just looked at the card as you're suggesting, you might think you could Equip at instant speed.