# Can I re-equip an equipped artifact to the same creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say I have [Sun Forger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=sunforger) equipped to my only creature on the battlefield. Can I re-equip Sun Forger to the creature it is currently equipped to? That way I can tutor a card with only one creature card out on the battle field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As our other [Can you re-equip equipment to the same creature?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/29886/can-you-re-equip-equipment-to-the-same-creature) question says, yes you can equip an equipment to a creature it is already equipped to.

However with Sunforger part of the cost of the ability is "*Unattach Sunforger*", this means that Sunforger will no longer be equipped to the creature it was equipped to prior to the ability being activated. This means that you are in fact **not** equipping the Sunforger to the creature that it is equipped to because the Sunforger is not equipped to any creature.